# Unable to retrieve values on database using specific query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to fetch data from Firebase DataBase on my project. I have been able to successfully retrieve the entire Object Data (Data with all the fields included). I am stuck at a point where I am trying to retrieve data applying few conditions. In this case trying to retrieve records with the name as searched by the user.

Below is my Firebase Database look.

[image]
[image]

**SearchNameActiviy.java**

I am fetching data here from the data base wherein i am filtering the data on "name" and comparing it to the searched value by user that is fetched from the getActivity method.

```
package com.example.sumeet.kalwardirectorytry1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchNameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String searchedValue;
    private static final String TAG = "myTag";
    List<Member_Pojo> memberList;
    ListView listViewHome;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_name);
        listViewHome = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_showSearchResults);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        searchedValue = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        Log.e(TAG, "Searched Value" + searchedValue);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searched Value is " + searchedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        memberList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member");
        Query query = reference.child("Member").orderByChild("name").equalTo(searchedValue);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot memberSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Member_Pojo member = memberSnapshot.getValue(Member_Pojo.class);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: " + member.getName());
                    memberList.add(member);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: " + memberList);
                }
                MembersListAdapter adapter = new MembersListAdapter(SearchNameActivity.this, memberList);
                listViewHome.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

**MembersListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.sumeet.kalwardirectorytry1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 05-07-2017.
 */

public class MembersListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Member_Pojo> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Member_Pojo> memberList;
    // CustomFilter filter;
  //  ArrayList<Member_Pojo> filterlist;


    public MembersListAdapter(Activity context, List<Member_Pojo> memberList) {
        super(context, R.layout.home_listview_display, memberList);
        this.context = context;
        this.memberList = memberList;
        //this.filterlist = (ArrayList<Member_Pojo>) memberList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_listview_display, null, true);

        TextView name_tv = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_display);
        TextView town_tv = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_town_display);
        TextView id = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        Member_Pojo member = memberList.get(position);

        name_tv.setText(member.getName());
        town_tv.setText(member.getTownP());
        id.setText(member.getId());

        return listViewItem;

    }

}

Member_Pojo.java
package com.example.sumeet.kalwardirectorytry1;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 04-07-2017.
 */

public class Member_Pojo {

    private String name, addressR, townR, districtR, stateR, countryR, pincodeR, mobileNumberR, addressPersonal, townP, districtP, stateP, countryP, pincodeP, mobileNumberP, occupationP, socialOrganizationS, memberAsS, townS, stateS, countryS;
    private String id;

    public Member_Pojo() {
    }


    public Member_Pojo(String name, String addressR, String townR, String districtR, String stateR, String countryR, String pincodeR, String mobileNumberR, String addressPersonal, String townP, String districtP, String stateP, String countryP, String pincodeP, String mobileNumberP, String occupationP, String socialOrganizationS, String memberAsS, String townS, String stateS, String countryS, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.addressR = addressR;
        this.townR = townR;
        this.districtR = districtR;
        this.stateR = stateR;
        this.countryR = countryR;
        this.pincodeR = pincodeR;
        this.mobileNumberR = mobileNumberR;
        this.addressPersonal = addressPersonal;
        this.townP = townP;
        this.districtP = districtP;
        this.stateP = stateP;
        this.countryP = countryP;
        this.pincodeP = pincodeP;
        this.mobileNumberP = mobileNumberP;
        this.occupationP = occupationP;
        this.socialOrganizationS = socialOrganizationS;
        this.memberAsS = memberAsS;
        this.townS = townS;
        this.stateS = stateS;
        this.countryS = countryS;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddressR() {
        return addressR;
    }

    public String getTownR() {
        return townR;
    }

    public String getDistrictR() {
        return districtR;
    }

    public String getStateR() {
        return stateR;
    }

    public String getCountryR() {
        return countryR;
    }

    public String getPincodeR() {
        return pincodeR;
    }

    public String getMobileNumberR() {
        return mobileNumberR;
    }

    public String getAddressPersonal() {
        return addressPersonal;
    }

    public String getTownP() {
        return townP;
    }

    public String getDistrictP() {
        return districtP;
    }

    public String getStateP() {
        return stateP;
    }

    public String getCountryP() {
        return countryP;
    }

    public String getPincodeP() {
        return pincodeP;
    }

    public String getMobileNumberP() {
        return mobileNumberP;
    }

    public String getOccupationP() {
        return occupationP;
    }

    public String getSocialOrganizationS() {
        return socialOrganizationS;
    }

    public String getMemberAsS() {
        return memberAsS;
    }

    public String getTownS() {
        return townS;
    }

    public String getStateS() {
        return stateS;
    }

    public String getCountryS() {
        return countryS;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Can you please correct me on my mistake ?
Presently i am not getting any error but the list view is not displaying any data.
I am guessing i am going wrong on my query to the database. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You both have `getReference("Member")` and `child("Member"`). Remove latter or change the `getReference("Member")` with `getReference()`

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member");
    Query query = reference.child("Member").orderByChild("name").equalTo(searchedValue);
```

Comment: Beyond words :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Beyond words :) Thanks a lot :)